# What is the difference between 体が動かない and 体が動けない?

Tags: word-choice

why 体が動かない mean can't my body instead of body won't move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "体が動かない" can mean both *My body won't move* and *I can't move my body*. I believe it's just matter of situation.

*I can't move my body* would fit better with "体が動か**せ**ない" though.

*Edit:* Forgot to mention that "体が動けない" doesn't sound natural to me.
If you meant to use it as "*My body won't move*", it's fine with "体が動かない" as I stated above. If you meant to use it as "*I can't move my body*", then use "体が動かせない", which sound more natural in most case.

So here goes the difference between "動かない" and "動かせない".

The word "動かない" is used when the thing you want to move does not behave as you want it to, for example, when the car does not move as you want it to.（車が思うように**動かない**。）

The word "動かせない" is used when you want to do something but it is impossible, for example, *I want to move the box from here, but it is too heavy to move.*（ここから箱を動かしたいけど、重すぎて**動かせない**。）